# Django QuerySet to search to different fields

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
result = Invoice.objects.filter(
                Q(client__in=Client.objects.filter(
                    Q(first_name__icontains=search_param) | Q(last_name__icontains=search_param))))

class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If both first and last name are typed, the search results in nothing. However, if only one of both is typed it works and that I can not understand since that is an OR statement with contains.

My logic is:

Joe Doe contains Joe, therefore the first condition matches and it should return the value found.

Comment: Can you show your `models.py`?

Comment: But `Joe` does not contain `Joe Doe`, so if your `search_param` value is `Joe Doe`, `first_name` is `Joe` and `last_name` is `Doe` your filter is correctly returning nothing. You'd need to find a way to break down your search term.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper that's what I thought. I was afraid this was happening. Guess I will have to split the string I receive and search separately then. :(

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper is right, but it is pretty easy to split and search for each, since Django's querysets are lazy. They don't execute SQL until the queryset is actually evaluated. I was going to show in this comment, but the formatting would have just made it more confusing. See my "answer" below for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to split the `search_param` and search on each entry. Since Django does not execute a query until it is evaluated, you can simply append filters to your queryset.

```
result = Invoice.objects.all()

for chars in search_param.split():
    result = result.filter(
        Q(client__in=Client.objects.filter(
            Q(first_name__icontains=chars)
            | Q(last_name__icontains=chars)
        )
    )

# This should show all who matched any name entered,
# even if you enter last name first.
print(results)
```